# Ghidra what's the meaning of _0_4_

Tags: ghidra

What does _0_4_ mean in ghidra?

[image]

Comment: Did you look at the disassembly that related to this line?

Comment: iirc ghidra uses the split notations to indicate bitmasks i might be mistaken since you accepted pavels answer and it has been upvoted also dont have ghidra at hand so cant confirm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is being used when there's a mismatch between type sizes in the decompiled code and Ghidra cannot show you that the whole variable is being modified.

Your `PUCHAR` - since it is a pointer and this is (probably) 64-bit is 8 bytes. But analyzing the disassembly Ghidra sees that only 4 bytes are being set to 0 in this line (for example a 32 bit register is used).

One of the fix you can apply is by correcting the type of `local_res8` (<kbd>CTRL+L</kbd>) but it might be the case that the type is ok, and in fact only lower 32-bits are being set..